# Error font in jackson

Tags: json, utf-8, jackson

Althought i set Encoding UTF8 for JsonGenerator but when i write string in that still error font

```
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(out, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
jsonGenerator.writeStringField("errorCode", "0");
jsonGenerator.writeStringField("responseData", "Tiếng Việt"); 
jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
jsonGenerator.close();
String jsonObject = out.toString(); //{"errorCode":"0","responseData":"Tiáº¿ng Viá»‡t"}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks so much!

Update:

I have found the reason why is dont work. You can try use StringWrite instead OutputStream. Look like @Alastair McCormack answer.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(sw);|
...
// add your content here
String jsonObject = sw.toString()
```

Comment: Would you please provide more information such as what error you get. Also, consider the suggestions mentioned on this page: [How to ask.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I tried your code, but nothing is wrong.

Comment: @ChenZhongPu Your jsonObject output = "Tiáº¿ng Viá»‡t" or "Tiếng Việt" ? Thanks for answer

Comment: my output is `{"errorCode":"0","responseData":"Tiếng Việt"}` @Nasper

Comment: @QualityCatalyst I posted my error. My input "Tiếng Việt" but my output = "Tiáº¿ng Viá»‡t". Thanks for help

Comment: @ChenZhongPu What jackson's version you use ? I use jackson-core-asl-1.9.2 is error font.

Comment: I use `Maven` to build it.  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: and I think the version is not the real problem.

Comment: @ChenZhongPu So you think where is it problem? I found so long but still cant know hix

Comment: I found problem why is error font. Because my project run in WebSphere. If i run it as java application, its still work. So I am looking for fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem is `out.toString()` as it'll use your locale to covert the bytes back to a Unicode String. This may be different from your WebSphere instance to your local machine.

Try:

```
String jsonObject = out.toString("UTF-8")
```

If you're sending this string to a browser, make sure the Content-Type headers are set correctly so the client knows what encoding it's receiving content in.

Suggestion:

If you don't use the bytes from `out`, you might want to consider using a StringWriter instead:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(sw);
...
// add your content here
String jsonObject = sw.toString()
```

This will keep the Strings in Unicode until the point you're ready to write the data out.

Comment: McComack I use StringWriter and It's worked. Thank you so much for a good answer.